# How to pass JSON string in UriTemplate using WCF without using Query string

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-rest

```
http://localhost:51238/RestService.svc/FOSLoadingS1Opening?Data=[
{ 
"Name":"Sachin", 
"City":"Bengalueu", 
"FimStatus":"false", 
"Deno1":"50", 
"Deno2":"100", 
"Deno3":"500", 
"Deno4":"2000", 
"IndtVal1":"2500", 
"IndtVal2":"5000"  }]
```

I am able to pass the json string with query string. But, When when i want pass the pass the without query string I am getting the error.

```
http://localhost:51238/RestService.svc/FOSLoadingS1Opening/[
{ 
"Name":"Sachin", 
"City":"Bengalueu", 
"FimStatus":"false", 
"Deno1":"50", 
"Deno2":"100", 
"Deno3":"500", 
"Deno4":"2000", 
"IndtVal1":"2500", 
"IndtVal2":"5000"  }]
```

When i pass above URL i am getting error "Bad Request".

I want to pass the json string without using query string. Please suggest how to achieve.

Comment: the only way is to use webinvoke (post) instead of webget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `WebInvoke` with method POST.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "SaveData/{id}")]
string SaveData(YourType typeObj);
```

Now from client side construct the object and send the json stringified data through ajax call.

```
    var obj = {
        "Name":"Sachin", 
        "City":"Bengalueu", 
        "FimStatus":"false", 
        ...
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/wcf.svc/SaveData/0",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("success..." + data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```